# Finding angle between two objects as seen from an axis

Tags: python, measurement

Suppose I have two cylinder objects that vary in Z-Location. Like this

[image: Cylinder Locations]

(Note: they move thanks to python-scripting)
Now when seen from the top z-axis it looks like this

[image]

Although they aren't overlaid on top of each other, is it possible to find the angle of their rotation. Like

[image: How I want it.]

Like virtually overlay the first cylinder on top of the second cylinder and find the angles as seen from top z-axis

Comment: Translation doesn't affect rotation, so you should be able to directly compare the obj.rotation properties